# Convert complex map to json

Tags: json, dictionary

I have two case classes: 
case class Key(String,String,Double)
case class Value(String,String)
I want to convert  a Map[Key,Value] to Json. What is the best possible way to do it??

Comment: u_try == we_try

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using c++ you can consider boost library and 
boost::property_tree::json_parser